# TinyMce вырезает теги video и iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, видео, tinymce

Редактор tinyMCE 4.5.0, используется плагин media, видео добавляется, даже проигрывается в самом редакторе, но при сохранении - вырезаются теги iframe и video (на backend приходит уже с вырезанными тегами) Если добавлять код вручную через object\embed, то видео сохраняется.
Инициализируется редактор в следующем порядке:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea#id_body',
            relative_urls: false,
            menubar: false,
            image_advtab: true,
            plugins: [ advlist autolink lists link image print preview imagetools', 'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen', 'media table contextmenu paste code emoticons'],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext pasteword | insert | underline bold italic strikethrough |  blockquote subscript superscript code | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist table emoticons outdent indent | ',
            media_filter_html: false,
            verify_html : false,
            extended_valid_elements : 'embed[param|src|type|width|height|flashvars|wmode|allowscriptaccess|allowfullscreen],iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder],div[*],p[*],object[width|height|classid|codebase|embed|param|data|frameborder|allowfullscreen],param[name|value]',
            cleanup : false,
            media_strict: false,
            valid_children : '+p[iframe],+span[iframe],+p[object],+span[object],+div[iframe],+iframe[iframe]'
        });
```

В чем ошибка? Что делаю не так?

Comment: Видимо проблема в редакторе, а может быть и при отправки на сервер.  Проверьте наблюдается ли проблема в версии 4.6.4?

Comment: Да, к сожалению наблюдается и в этой версии

Comment: вам придется копать библиотеку или писать в поддержку `tinymce`. попробуйте в исходниках найти метод `fixDoc` может с ним, что не так.